# how to get the details when click the jquery mobile filter data?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, web-services, jquery-mobile

I am creating a jquery mobile site.I want to get the child details using the jquery mobile filters.Now I am able to fire the data when I enter the child name. then I will click the "search" button. It will show matching name from the database. But when i click the name(such as "Reegan" or "Reegan1" ), its not populating rest of the values from the database.

Then I want to go other page and print the details of the child.I am using the json Url to pull the values from data base .Please help me to solve the problem.

This is my code:

```
$("#btnSearch").click(function () {
    var child_name = $("#search-1").val();
    helper.actionGet("http://.../SearchChildJSON", {
            name: child_name
        },
        function (data) {
            console.log(data);
            var rec_data = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
            sessionStorage.setItem("AllData",data);
            $.each(rec_data, function (index, value) {
                $("#push_name").append("<a id='"+value.CMOId+"' href='#' class='ui-btn ui-shadow ui-corner-all'>" + value.FirstName + "</a>");
            });
        });
    $("#push_name").on("click","a",function(val) {
        console.log(val);
    });
});
```

I am try to get the data of selected filter data such as "Reegan".my console reply

```
m.Event {originalEvent: MouseEvent, type: "click", isDefaultPrevented: function, timeStamp: 1416223135795, jQuery111109369461725000292: true…}
```

Image :

[image]

JQuery mobile html file :

```
<div data-role="content">
        <label for="search-1">Child:</label>
        <form>
           <input data-type="search" class="filterControlgroup-input" id="search-1"       placeholder="Search Child...">
        </form>
           <div data-role="controlgroup" data-filter="true" data-input=".filterControlgroup-input" data-filter-reveal="true" id="push_name">
        </div>
</div>
<div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
       <button class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-btn-inline" class="btnSearch" id="btnSearch">Search</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Delegate `click` event to dynamically added anchors (buttons).

```
$(document).on("pagecreate", "#pageID", function () {
   $("#push_name").on("click", "a", function () {
     var btnID = this.id, /* or $(this)[0].id */
         btnText = this.innerText; /* or $(this).text() */
   });
});
```

Comment: thanks bro.I get "m.Event {originalEvent: MouseEvent, type: "click", isDefaultPrevented: function, timeStamp: 1416202087374, jQuery111109532860720064491: true…}" when i give a parameter with in the function.but i con't able to get the 'reegan' details.

Comment: @reegan29 can yo update your post with the code causing that error?

Comment: @reegan29 dont add your code inside `$("#btnSearch").click(function () {` just copy/paste my code and replace `#pageID` with id of the page you add listview to.

Comment: @reegan29 btw, what value you want to retrieve from the anchor? id or text?

Comment: bro http://eproviderservice.dev/eProvider.svc/SearchChildJSON this json url contain the child details such as child firstname,lastname ,place,age....I want get those details via selecting the particular   child.I want both Id and text bro